# Sending Objects from Client to Server

Tags: java, swing

I'm writing a program where the server draws shapes from the PaintPanel in server application and where the client can see those shapes in its own application. Currently, the server can send the shape data to the client but the client still can't see it.

Server code for sending shape data

```
private void sendShape(Graphics drawedShape) {
        try {
            oos.writeObject(drawedShape);
            oos.flush();
            dispMessage("\n Teacher:" + "Shape sent!" );
        }catch(IOException e){
            jta.append("\nError");
        }
    }
```

Client code for receiving the shape data

```
private void processConn() throws IOException {
        send("Successful");
        setButtonEnabled(true);
        String msg = "";
        Graphics object;

        do {
            try                

            {
                   Object incomingObject = ois.readObject();

                   if(incomingObject.getClass().toString().contains("Graphics"))
                   {
                          object = (Graphics) ois.readObject();
                          dispMessage("\n" + object);

                   } else
                   {
                          dispMessage("\n" + "Unknown object!");
                   }
            }

            catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                dispMessage("Unknown");
            }
        }
      while (!msg.equals("S:ExitTheSystem"));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see some significant problems with your code and offer some solutions:

1. Don't read from your stream on the Swing event thread as this will block the thread potentially freezing the application
2. Don't send and receive a Graphics object but rather a logical (non-GUI, non-Graphic) object -- the shape parameters and color for instance, and then use that that to draw at the client.
3. Consider having the data sent and received in a text-readable fashion, such as XML or JSON text. This makes debugging a whole lot easier.
4. If you absolutely must send binary serialized data (e.g., if it is an assignment requirement), then consider sending  Shape objects, objects that implement the `java.awt.Shape` interface, as these are readily drawable with your client JPanel's paintComponent method's Graphics (actually cast to a Graphics2D) object.
5. Use  a SwingWorker to receive and process the incoming data, using specifically its publish/process method pair to help do this.

For a more specific answer and possibly code, consider posting your best [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) program with your question

Comment: Thank you, I will go with your second solution I think it will work better. @DontKnowMuchButGettingBetter

Comment: @RocketMonkey: Note though that as far as I understand things, Shape objects do not carry Color information, and that would have to be sent separate or combined in a custom object